# R - random number generation

Tags: r, random

I want to generate a numeric vector of random numbers between 0 and 5,000 of length 2,500 and call it x.

Then I want to make a numeric vector y of all the numbers between 0 and 5,000 which aren't in x, which by definition is also length 2,500.

Then for each of these vectors I'd like to extract the corresponding row numbers from a table. 
Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `which by definition is also length 2,500.` Do you mean that the first vector shouldn't be random, since random would imply it _could_ be all zeroes. That'd leave the values 1-5000 in the second vector.

Comment: We need more information. Is sampling done with replacement? If not, this should get you started: `main <- sample(1:5000, 5000);
main <- matrix(main, ncol = 2);
head(main)`.

Comment: Okay, I think my original was badly worded. 
I want x to be length 2,500, filled with numbers drawn randomly from between 0 and 5000 without replacement

Cheers

Comment: @RomanLuštrik that seems to be doing what I wanted, 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as such (click the grey check mark under the score - it should turn green). I don't have a OCD, but it feels nice to have closure. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. The `main` object holds a table with two columns (you can think of them as your `x` and `y`).

```
main <- sample(1:5000, 5000)
main <- matrix(main, ncol = 2)
head(main)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 3146 4834
[2,] 4129 4297
[3,]  510 1843
[4,] 4513 1167
[5,] 1281 2550
[6,] 1076 4377
```